# list of functions with parameters

Tags: python

I need to obtain a list of functions, where my function is defined as follows:

```
import theano.tensor as tt

def tilted_loss(y,f,q):
    e = (y-f)
    return q*tt.sum(e)-tt.sum(e[e<0])
```

I attempted to do

```
qs = np.arange(0.05,1,0.05)
q_loss_f = [tilted_loss(q=q) for q in qs]
```

however, get the error `TypeError: tilted_loss() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y' and 'f'`. I attempted the simpler `a = tilted_loss(q=0.05)` with the same result.

How do you go about creating this list of functions when parameters are required? Similar questions on SO consider the case where parameters are not involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
q_loss_f = [functools.partial(tilted_loss, q=q) for q in qs]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways you can solve this problem. Both ways require you know the default values for y and f.

With the current function, there's simply no way for the Python interpreter to know the value of y and f when you call tilted_loss(q=0.05). y and f are simply undefined & unknown.

**Solution (1): Add default values**

We can fix this by adding default values for the function, for example, if default values are: y = 0, f = 1:

```
def tilted_loss(q, y=0, f=1):
    # original code goes here
```

Note that arguments with default values have to come AFTER non-default arguments (i.e q).

**Solution (2): Specify default values during function call**

Alternatively, just specify the default values every time you call that function. (Solution 1 is better)